# Replicate records from exist version to new version in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with some rows with version number 1 these rows have their
    respective Parent Id if parent id is null then it is parent other wise
    child    with parent id, and I want to write query to copy all rows 
    from version number 1 to 2 and insert new rows with new respective parentid.
    Below is my table and some data script.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Menu](
[MenuId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MenuName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ParentId] [bigint] NULL,
[VersionNumber] [bigint] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Menu] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[MenuId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber])     VALUES (1, N'Customer', NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (2, N'Home', NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (3, N'About', NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (4, N'Add Customer', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (5, N'Administration', NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (6, N'Edit Customer', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (7, N'Tenant', 5, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (8, N'Manage Contact', 5, 1)
 INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (9, N'Users', 5, 1)
 INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (10, N'Customer List', 1, 1)
 INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (11, N'Contact', NULL, 1)`enter code here`
   SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Menu] OFF
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling there is more to the issue then what I am reading, but if you just want to duplicate the data and change the version number from 1 to 2, then this will work.

```
INSERT  INTO dbo.Menu
        ( MenuName,
          ParentId,
          VersionNumber )
        SELECT  m.MenuName,
                m.ParentId,
                2
        FROM    Menu AS m
        WHERE   m.VersionNumber = 1
```

Comment: He wants the new inserts to have the "similar" parent-to-child values after the insert.  That is the trick.  Aka, this will do the basic insert, but will not have the new-rows child-to-parent mappings.

Answer (score 0):

This one was a little tricky.

But below is a working solution.

The "MERGE" with the output values and original values (getting both types of values into the #Holder table) is the trick.

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and TABLE_NAME = N'Menu' and TABLE_TYPE = N'BASE TABLE' ) 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Menu] 
END 
GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Menu](
[MenuId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MenuName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ParentId] [bigint] NULL,
[VersionNumber] [bigint] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Menu] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[MenuId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber])     VALUES (1, N'Customer', NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (2, N'Home', NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (3, N'About', NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (4, N'Add Customer', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (5, N'Administration', NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (6, N'Edit Customer', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (7, N'Tenant', 5, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (8, N'Manage Contact', 5, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (9, N'Users', 5, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (10, N'Customer List', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Menu] ([MenuId], [MenuName], [ParentId], [VersionNumber]) VALUES (11, N'Contact', NULL, 1)


   SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Menu] OFF

   select * from [dbo].[Menu] 


    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Holder') IS NOT NULL
    begin
            drop table #Holder
    end

    /* The "mapping values" holder/tracking table */
    CREATE TABLE #Holder
    ( 
    --SurrogateKeyIDENTITY int not null IDENTITY (1,1) , 
    OriginalMenuId [bigint]  NULL,
    OriginalParentId [bigint] NULL,
    NewMenuSurrogateKey int null ,
    NewParentIdSurrogateKey int null
    )


/* This is the key trick.  You need to do the INSERT and keep track of old and new surrogate keys.  The MERGE trick is the only way to get values into the #holder...combining "output" values and original values */
MERGE INTO [dbo].[Menu] pc
USING [dbo].[Menu] AS sourceTable 
ON  1 = 0 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT([MenuName], [VersionNumber])
   Values([MenuName] , [VersionNumber] + 1 ) /* Here is your "plus one" for the Version */
Output sourceTable.MenuId , sourceTable.ParentId , inserted.MenuID INTO 
  #Holder (OriginalMenuId , [OriginalParentId] , NewMenuSurrogateKey );

Select 'Before the NewParentIdSurrogateKey is Updated Values' as Lab1 ,  * from #Holder


Update holderAsParent Set NewParentIdSurrogateKey = holderAsChild.NewMenuSurrogateKey
/* You can comment out the previous update and uncomment the next select statement to see what the update is trying to do */
/* Select 'Here1' as Lab1 ,  holderAsChild.NewMenuSurrogateKey, '----' as Sep1, holderAsChild.* , '----' as Sep2 , holderAsParent.* */
from
#Holder holderAsChild 
join #Holder holderAsParent on holderAsChild.OriginalMenuId = holderAsParent.OriginalParentId


Select 'ShouldHaveAllTheMappingValuesInTheHolderNow' as Lab1 ,  * from #Holder


Update dbo.Menu Set [ParentId] = holder.NewParentIdSurrogateKey
from 
dbo.Menu men join #Holder holder on men.MenuId = holder.NewMenuSurrogateKey
where holder.NewParentIdSurrogateKey iS NOT NULL

Select 'Final Results' as Lab1 ,  * from dbo.Menu


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Holder') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #Holder
end

/* Sanity Check */


Select COALESCE(parent.MenuName + ' -- ', '') + child.MenuName as ParentThenChildMenuName, child.VersionNumber
from
    [dbo].[Menu] child
    left join
    [dbo].[Menu] parent
    on child.ParentId = parent.MenuId
where child.VersionNumber = 1
order by parent.MenuName , child.MenuName



Select COALESCE(parent.MenuName + ' -- ', '') + child.MenuName as ParentThenChildMenuName, child.VersionNumber
from
    [dbo].[Menu] child
    left join
    [dbo].[Menu] parent
    on child.ParentId = parent.MenuId
where child.VersionNumber = 2
order by parent.MenuName , child.MenuName
```

Below is a reference.  This was the little hint to led to using MERGE in the "from_table_name" for this particular situation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx
“from_table_name”
Is a column prefix that specifies a table included in the FROM clause of a DELETE, UPDATE, or MERGE statement that is used to specify the rows to update or delete.